# Why do queries submitted via the Hive CLI not show up in the ResourceManager, but those via the Hue Beeswax interface do?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

I've got a Cloudera Hadoop installation (CDH4) which runs the Yarn framework, and I've got Hue installed as well.

I've noticed that when I submit a Hive query via the Hue (Beeswax) interface, the resulting mapreduce job shows up in the resourcemanager web UI, as well as the Hue 'Job Browser' interface. However, if I run the `hive` cli application on any of the nodes and run the same query from there, it doesn't appear to hit any of the nodemanagers, although it does return the correct results.

The only difference I can think of is that the Hue job runs as the user I'm logged into Hue as, whereas the hive cli job runs as the user that started the hive cli, which is a different user.

I would expect queries submitted via the hive CLI to show up in the resource manager. Is there any reason why they are not?

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged-in as the same user in Hue? Hue's JobBrowser filter shows you only your own jobs by default. You can reset the username filter and check if they are other jobs?

Comment: I'm logged in as root on the CLI, but a separate user on Hue. The problem is that I'm not looking at the jobs through hue, I'm looking at them directly on the resourcemanager, which I believe shows all jobs on the cluster. Hive CLI jobs don't show up there.